# MakeFile Error: "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect"

Tags: makefile

I encountered this error when I was running my makefile:

```
clean: cleanlib
cleanlib:
    ( cd "D:\third party components\arpack96\ARPACK\BLAS"; "D:\third party components\arpack96\ARPACK\make" clean )
```

The command I use to run the make file is

```
make clean
```

This is incomprehensible, as both the paths are ***actually*** available on my machine ( I took great care to check it).

I am using Windows XP, not sure whether that makes a difference or not.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the back slashes to forward slashes and see if that helps:

```
( cd "D:/third party components/arpack96/ARPACK/BLAS"; "D:/third party components/arpack96/ARPACK/make" clean )
```

Alternatively, you can escape the backslashes by doubling them.

Comment: If you're not already on the D drive, try adding the /D parameter to "cd".

Comment: Were you on the D drive before you did the "cd"?  cd does not change the current drive unless you use the /D parameter.